# Error in R code. (buckley james estimator)

Tags: r, regression, multiple-regression, survival

I am performing survival analysis (Buckley James estimator), using restricted cubic splines, but in `R` I get a blank error message and multiple warnings such as this one:

```
fewer than 3 unique knots.  Frequency table of variable:
x
 0  1
34 84
```

and this:

```
3 knots requested with 2 unique values of x.  knots set to 0 interior values.
```

What does that mean? How to correct it?

[image]

Comment: You cannot fit restricted cubic splines with just two $x$ values (0 and 1). I'd recommend you look through the description of restricted cubic splines in Harrell's *Regression Modeling Strategies*.

Comment: (Actually, I don't see this as close-worthy *because it's about R*. The underlying problem is one with splines, independent of the software used.)

Comment: @Stephan I agree on the whole, but the current form of the question isn't best suited to future searchers on that topic. The question can clearly be rephrased to be less software-dependent and would then be a much better fit for this site, at least in terms of our [help/on-topic].

Comment: (I have voted to leave open but do hope the Q is edited.)

Comment: This is legitimately an edge case. I am leaning towards closing & reopening when it has been edited.